# META-INF/MSFTSIG.RSA not merging even after trying all merge strategies (sbt assembly)

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am trying to create fat jar using sql-server dependencies , that is when few dependencies might have crept in for the Azure package.

"META-INF/MSFTSIG.RSA"

Even though I tried to delete it from cache, it did not work. 
Tried the suggested "provided" flag, still it does not work and throws the same error as below.

### Tried using merge strategy mentioned below

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) => 
{ 
  case x if x.startsWith("META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA") => MergeStrategy.last 
  case x if x.startsWith("META-INF/MSFTSIG.RSA") => MergeStrategy.deduplicate 
  case x if x.startsWith("META-INF/mailcap") => MergeStrategy.last 
  case x if x.startsWith("plugin.properties") => MergeStrategy.last 
  case x if x.startsWith("Driver.properties") => MergeStrategy.last 
  case x if x.startsWith("Logger.class") => MergeStrategy.last 
  case x if x.startsWith("Driver.properties") => MergeStrategy.last 
  case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first 
  case PathList("org", "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.first 
  case x => old(x) 
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first 
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard 
  case x => MergeStrategy.first 
} 
}
```

---

Error

---

```
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/BCKEY.DSA' with strategy 'discard' 
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/BCKEY.SF' with strategy 'discard' 
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' with strategy 'discard' 
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' with strategy 'discard' 
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:assembly' for the full output. 
[error] (*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following: 
[error] /Users/vrai/.ivy2/cache/com.microsoft.azure/azure-keyvault/jars/azure-keyvault-0.9.3.jar:META-INF/MSFTSIG.RSA 
[error] /Users/vrai/.ivy2/cache/com.microsoft.azure/azure-core/jars/azure-core-0.9.3.jar:META-INF/MSFTSIG.RSA 
[error] /Users/vrai/.ivy2/cache/com.microsoft.azure/adal4j/jars/adal4j-1.0.0.jar:META-INF/MSFTSIG.RSA
```

---

What am I doing wrong here ?

Other configs:

Spark - 1.6.2

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

sbt version 13.5

plugin.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2") 

logLevel := Level.Error
```